# Urn contains equal numbers of white and black balls. Probability that there will be as many W balls as B balls among the balls drawn.

Tags: probability

We randomly draw an even number of balls from an urn containing $n$ white and $n$ black balls. All distinguishable samples containing an even number of balls, including the sample with a count of $0$, are equally likely. Determine the probability that there will be as many white balls as black balls among the balls drawn.

Ok, after thinking a bit more about it, here is what I found:

If we have $n = 1$, there are $2$ groups of options:

1. group, there are $0$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+0$B balls)

2. group, there are $2$ balls in a sample:

- $1$W ball ($+1$B ball)

If we have $n = 2$, there are $3$ groups of options:

1. group, there are $0$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+0$B balls)

2. group, there are $2$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+1$B ball)
- $2$W balls ($+0$B balls)

3. group, there are $4$ balls in a sample:

- $2$W balls ($+2$B balls)

If we have $n = 3$, there are $4$ groups of options:

1. group, there are $0$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+0$B balls)

2. group, there are $2$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+1$B ball)
- $2$W balls ($+0$B balls)

3. group, there are $4$ balls in a sample:

- $1$W ball ($+3$B balls)
- $2$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $3$W balls ($+1$B ball)

4. group, there are $6$ balls in a sample:

- $3$W balls ($+3$B balls)

If we have $n = 4$, there are $5$ groups of options:

1. group, there are $0$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+0$B balls)

2. group, there are $2$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+1$B ball)
- $2$W balls ($+0$B balls)

3. group, there are $4$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+4$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+3$B balls)
- $2$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $3$W balls ($+1$B ball)
- $4$W balls ($+0$B balls)

4. group, there are $6$ balls in a sample:

- $2$W balls ($+4$B balls)
- $3$W balls ($+3$B balls)
- $4$W balls ($+2$B balls)

5. group, there are $8$ balls in a sample:

- $4$W balls ($+4$B balls)

If we have $n = 5$, there are $6$ groups of options:

1. group, there are $0$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+0$B balls)

2. group, there are $2$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+1$B ball)
- $2$W balls ($+0$B balls)

3. group, there are $4$ balls in a sample:

- $0$W balls ($+4$B balls)
- $1$W ball ($+3$B balls)
- $2$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $3$W balls ($+1$B ball)
- $4$W balls ($+0$B balls)

4. group, there are $6$ balls in a sample:

- $1$W ball ($+5$B balls)
- $2$W balls ($+4$B balls)
- $3$W balls ($+3$B balls)
- $4$W balls ($+2$B balls)
- $5$W balls ($+1$B ball)

5. group, there are $8$ balls in a sample:

- $3$W balls ($+5$B balls)
- $4$W ball ($+4$B ball)
- $5$W balls ($+3$B balls)

6. group, there are $10$ balls in a sample:

- $5$W balls ($+5$B balls)

The cases in which there are as many white balls as black balls are easy to count. In each group of options there is exactly one. Therefore we have as many of those as there are many groups: that is $n+1$. Therefore, the numerator of the probability is done.

The denominator is a harder thing to count. Given $n$, I need to know how many options are there. I know that the options create sort of "piramide" for each $n$: the number of options in groups increases by $2$ until we reach the middle group, then the number of options in groups decreases by $2$. For odd $n$ there is always en even number of groups and for even $n$ there is always an odd number of groups.

I don't know how to count those.

Comment: Where did $\frac{1}{n+1}$ come from?

Comment: Are you saying that the draws BBWW and BWBW are distinguishable  or indistinguishable?

Comment: @user469053 form the probability of drawing a sample containing an even number of balls - they are equally likely.

Comment: @Henry indistinguishable.

Comment: @thefool Your problem specifically states that they are distinguishable, which makes the $\frac{1}{n+1}$ factor incorrect.

Comment: The factor of $\frac{1}{n+1}$ holds if drawing zero balls is equally probable as drawing $2$. But if all distinguishable samples are equally likely, then none,none, $BB$, $BW$, $WB$, and $WW$ are all equally likely, so the probability of drawing $0$ balls is only a fourth of the probability of drawing $2$, hence drawing zero and two are not equally likely.

Comment: I do not see how you physically draw balls.  For $n=2$ the possibilities could be the five: -, BB, BW, WW, BBWW, of which three have equal numbers of black and white.  For general $n$ there seem to be $\left\lceil \dfrac{(n+1)^2}2\right\rceil =\dfrac{2n^2+4n+3+(-1)^n }{4}$ possibilities of which $n+1$  have equal numbers of black and white.

Comment: "All distinguishable samples have equal probability". That means if you draw $2k$ balls, $P(0W) = P(1W) = P(2W) = \dots = P(2kW)$. There are $2k+1$ cases each equally probable, the case you are after, $P(kW)$, is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the easier case, odd $n$: For any given white ball count, there is one black ball count that is equal, and there are $\frac {n+1}2$ black ball counts that make the total even. Thus the probability that the white and black ball counts are equal is $\frac2{n+1}$.

For even $n$, things are only slightly more complicated. For a given white ball count, there is again one black ball count that makes the counts equal, but now there are $\frac n2$ black ball counts that make the total even if the white ball count is odd and $\frac n2+1$ if the white ball count is even. Since there are $\frac n2$ odd white ball counts and $\frac n2+1$ even white ball counts, that yields the probability

$$
\frac{n+1}{\frac n2\cdot\frac n2+\left(\frac n2+1\right)\left(\frac n2+1\right)}=\frac{2(n+1)}{n^2+2n+2}\;.
$$